# Saving worksheets with forms as pdf

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, userform, export-to-pdf

I'm trying to save a worksheet as PDF and I was successful at doing this, but when I open the generated PDF file all the textboxes in the sheet are deformed.

How can I keep the ratio of the exported textboxes?

I'm using a button in the worksheet that executes the following code:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Select

Sheets(1).Activate

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:="\\10.18.105.44\Setor Proteção RDs\01 - Ordens de Ajustes\Banco de ordens\AL" & alimentador & "\" & nome_arquivo & ".pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True

Sheets(1).Select
Range("D2").Select
```

Comment: Please add your *Edit* as an answer below which you can accept later to confirm resolution and for future readers who face your same issue. Also indicate where you specified *zoom* as code does not show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that this only occurs when i try to save with the zoom of the workbook larger than 100%, when i print with zoom at 100% it goes like a charm.